# @Autowired on a constructor of a Scala class

Tags: spring, scala

I have a simple question, How could I use spring @Autowired on a constructor of this Scala class?

```
class MessageMBeanExporter(messageDirectory: MessageDirectory) extends MBeanExporter with SmartLifecycle {
      .....
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3388) and [this link](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Syntax-for-Annotations-on-Constructor-td2002238.html), from 2.8+ you could do:

```
class MessageMBeanExporter @Autowired() (messageDirectory: MessageDirectory) extends MBeanExporter with SmartLifecycle {
      .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it, and if it works fine, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

I've added support for @Autowired on the constructor of a Scala object into the spring-scala project. This is only (at time of writing) in the nightly snapshot.

This allows you to do

```
@Component
@Autowired
class Service(dep : Dependency) { }
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala

Comment: This does not work for me (scala 2.11), but putting `@Autowired()` between the class name and the constructor does.... `class MyClazz @Autowired() (myBean: Bean)...`