# How can I use YAML properties with constructor injection in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I know this should be a piece of cake but I'm just not getting anywhere.

In my Spring Boot app, in the application.yml file, I have an entry like so:

```
some:
    constructor:
        property: value
```

And I have a spring service (this is fake but demonstrates the problem):

```
package somepackage;

@Service
public class DummyService {
    public DummyService(@Value("${some.constructor.property}") String path) {}
}
```

Startup fails, though:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dummyService' defined in file [...(the class
>   file)... ]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [somepackage.DummyService]: No default constructor found;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   somepackage.DummyService.()

How can I convince Spring that it should use the non-empty constructor, and it should get that constructor parameter from the YAML file? Note: I'm not using any XML bean config files or anything, and would prefer not to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the @Autowired annotation on your constructor.

```
@Autowired
public DummyService(@Value("${some.constructor.property}") String path) {}
```

Comment: Ah, I had @Autowired in the wrong place. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

And just in case someone else is trying to do this in Scala -- which is what I was really trying to do, but wanted to get the answer in Java before trying it with Scala -- this works:

```
@Service
class DummyService @Autowired()(@Value("${some.constructor.property}") val path: String) {

}
```

This is covered in [this SO case for scala constructor autowiring.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972896/autowired-on-a-constructor-of-a-scala-class)